# How to enumerate this correctly by Unix tools for pdfjam?

Tags: bash, shell, files, wildcards, sort

I need correct enumeration for the command `pdfjam *.pdf --nup 1x1`. 
There is nothing for the task in the manuals of `pdfjam` and `pdfjoin` so I am thinking Bash approach and/or `find` approach. 
Example of failed output without correct enumeration where I left out some repetition

```
ls -1 *
10 Heart Disorders.pdf
11 Red Blood Cell Disorders.pdf
...
19 Kidney Disorders.pdf
1 Cell Injury.pdf
20 Lower Urinary Tract and Male Reproductive Disorders.pdf
21 Female Reproductive Disorders and Breast Disorders.pdf
2 Inflammation and Repair.pdf
4 Water.pdf
5a Prematurity and intrauterine growth retardation.pdf
5 Genetic and Developmental Disorders.pdf
6 Environmental Pathology.pdf
...
9 Vascular Disorders.pdf
```

Expected output

```
1
2 
...
5
5a
... 
10
11
...
20
21
```

One challenge is the existence of `5...` and `5a...`.

OS: Debian 8.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
(LC_ALL=C; pdfjam ./*.pdf(n) --nup 1x1)
```

would work. `(n)` is a `zsh` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) for numeric sort. In the C locale, `"5a "` sorts after `"5 G"` as the space sorts before `a`. In some other locales, `"a "` could sort before `" G"` because the spaces and case would be ignored in the first pass (and `A` comes before `G`)

With other shells and on GNU or compatible systems, you could do:

```
printf '%s\0' ./* | LC_ALL=C sort -t/ -znk2 |
  xargs -r0 sh -c 'pdfjam "$@" --nup 1x1' sh
```

Note that if the list of files is too big, while with the `zsh` approach, you'd get an error, here, it would run several `pdfjam`'s which is probably not what you want either (and could remain unnoticed).

Instead of using `LC_ALL=C` above to make sure space sorts before `a`, another approach could be to sort numerically but on ties, to sort lexically (as per the locale rules) on the first field only:

```
printf '%s\0' [0-9]* | sort -z -k1n -k1,1 |
  xargs -r0 sh -c 'pdfjam "$@" --nup 1x1' sh
```

That would allow `5a` to sort before `5B` if case is ignored for sorting in your locale. `05a` would still sort before `5` though.

With `bash` 4.4 and above, you can also do:

```
readarray -td '' files < <(
  printf '%s\0' [0-9]* | sort -z -k1n -k1,1)
pdfjam "${files[@]}" --nup 1x1
```

Comment: Confirmed, output as expected! - - I am thinking this `(n)`. Is `(n)` part of glob or Zsh? Hmm, I think it is part of Zsh. Any links for it. What do you call it in Zsh?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영, see edit

Comment: - - I am thinking the irst command. Can you reverse the enumeration easily by this approach?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 `*.pdf(nOn)` for the reverse order.

Comment: How did you find it in the docs? - - I read it intuitively (from max n) to start (On).